add ipv6 address in /etc/network/interfaces
I'm trying to add IPv6 static address to my config, with instruction from provider, but this didn't work. ping doesn't respond.
What am I doing wrong?
Ubuntu 22.04
IPv6 Adress data:
address 2A03:4900:FFFC:1:0:0:0:3A  
mask FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:0:0:0:0:0  
gateway 2A03:4900:FFFC:0:0:0:0:1  

/etc/network/interfaces


Why are you editing /etc/network/interfaces and not using Netplan, like Ubuntu does by default?

Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use [code block]s for formatting
